# How to pick up a powerup by clicking or tapping on it

Tags: unity

I have a powerup that randomly drops from enemies. Right now I have it set up using `onTriggerEnter2D` and am checking for the `player` collider tag for the pickup to take effect.

```
    public class FireRatePowerUpScript : MonoBehaviour
{


    public float incrementRate = 1.3f;
    private Animator anim;

    private Weapon weapon;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.tag == "Player")
        {
            weapon = collision.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Weapon>();
            weapon.fireRate *= incrementRate;
            anim.SetTrigger("goPoof");
            Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I change it so that instead of the player character  bumping into it I have the player click or tap on it to activate/register?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked into [what messages Monobehaviours support](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) for mouse interactions, similar to the ones you're already using to detect physics interactions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391708/how-to-detect-click-touch-events-on-ui-and-gameobjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `OnMouseDown` method? It's a message called on `MonoBehaviour`.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
     weapon = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player").GetComponentInChildren<Weapon>();
     weapon.fireRate *= incrementRate;
     anim.SetTrigger("goPoof");
     Destroy(gameObject, 1f);
}
```

[See the Unity documentation on this method here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)